# How to use texture atlas with Threejs (r65)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Since the new threejs revision (r65) is released, the uvOffset and uvScale is moved to texture.offset and texture.repeate.

Unfortunately, the texture.offset is not working for me what I am trying to accomplish. I want to display multiple sprites in a scene that all use the same texture. The texture is a texture atlas with different tiles. If I change the texture.offset, the texture is changed for all sprites within the scene. Is there any solution to just change the offset individually for each sprite?

I guess uvOffset did this job very well and I don't understand why it is moved.

Here is some code to see what I am trying to do:

```
var gui_texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/button.png');

var btn_material1 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map:gui_texture } );
btn_material1.map.offset.set(0.5,0);
var button = new THREE.Sprite(btn_material1);
button1.position.set(-screen_half_x+50, screen_half_y-25, 1);
button1.scale.set(100, 50, 1);
gui_node.add(button1);

var btn_material2 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map:gui_texture } );
btn_material2.map.offset.set(-0.5,0);
var button2 = new THREE.Sprite(btn_material2);
button2.position.set(-screen_half_x+50, screen_half_y-150, 1);
button2.scale.set(100, 50, 1.0);
gui_node.add(button2);
```

Sincerely,

Markus

Comment: There is a three.js example of using sprite sheets: http:// threejs.org/examples/misc_ubiquity_test2.html. Search the source file for the comment "SPRITES - from Sprite Sheet".

Answer (score 1):

I realise that is not the prettiest... but try with this:

```
var texture1 = new THREE.Texture();
texture1.offset.set( 0.5, 0 );

var texture2 = new THREE.Texture();
texture2.offset.set( - 0.5, 0 );

var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
loader.load( 'images/button.png', function ( image ) {

    texture1.image = image;
    texture1.needsUpdate = true;

    texture2.image = image;
    texture2.needsUpdate = true;

} );

var button1 = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map:texture1 } ) );
button1.position.set( - screen_half_x + 50, screen_half_y - 25, 1 );
button1.scale.set( 100, 50, 1 );
gui_node.add( button1 );

var button2 = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map:texture2 } ) );
button2.position.set( - screen_half_x + 50, screen_half_y - 150, 1 );
button2.scale.set( 100, 50, 1.0 );
gui_node.add( button2 );
```