# Multiple textures to one face of a cube using Three.js

Tags: three.js

There is a very large image . Now this image is split into small size images(where if we put all these small size images at their respective positions it forms the original image).
I want to map these small images to a face of a cube at their respective positions. So that it should look as the mapping the original image itself.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362048/

Comment: A possible way, not sure if it's good. Draw your small images in needed positions on 2D canvas and use canvas as one texture on the face. Or create cube with needed number of faces, use more segments and map each image to different face.