# Three.js texture optimization methods

Tags: three.js

What would be the best ways to handle many textures in a scene apart from using low quality images? I was thinking about using texture atlases instead of separate images seen in the answer of mrdoob: [How to use texture atlas with threejs r65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362048/how-to-use-texture-atlas-with-threejs-r65)

However that method seemed suspicious to me since we create a new THREE.Texture object each time. Does THREE.js handle the optimization of different textures using the same image by itself? If not what would be a good way to send the image only once to the GPU and to use it many times without resending it?

Thanks!